# JSON/JSP - Make JSON text as link

Tags: json, jsp

I was asked to code a local social network
Each profile (JSP page) has a list of friends inside a div which is populated with a JSON file
I would like to know if there is an option to make the text inside the div act as a link to a different friend's profile (JSP style)?

Thanks in advance,
Einav

Comment: Hey man I can answer in terms of HTML and Javascript. I have used angular on frontend. Let me know if that can be helpful. Here is the logical explanation though. When you are calling the whole JSON chunk and representing it in repeat in your div, make arrangements where their name is displayed and then formulate system to make request with their specific user id or something. Whatever you are using to call data of a specific user.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that, is there any code example you can show me? I'll post my code which uploads the JSON file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/RkykR/ Please check this link. JSON data is populated their in a div. Then read the comment I have written above, I hope that you'll get my point.

Comment: Thanks for your input however I still don't see how I can make the text in div act as a link to another page

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('friend-list.json', function(data) { 
            var html = [];
            $.each(data, function(index, d) {
                html.push(d.Name, ", ",
                          "Status: ",d.Status, "<br>", "<br>"); 
                });
            $("#friend-list").html(html.join(''));
            }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                alert("error occurred!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Or Benvenisti",
        "Status": "Online"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Liat Leibel",
        "Status": "Online"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Noy Lashon",
        "Status": "Offline"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Einav Chazen",
        "Status": "Online"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Tal Tolaat",
        "Status": "Offline"
    }
]
```